# How to add long equation in the AMCS style

Tags: equations, two-column

I am using the [AMCS template](https://www.amcs.uz.zgora.pl/downloads/Instructions_AMCS.pdf) and I am willing to add a long equation which does not fit into one column (in AMCS the text is split into two different columns). Now, breaking it into several lines would decrease its readability. Thus, I would like to use both columns for my equation.

Could I do that without colliding with the AMCS style?

Comment: Try  the `split` environment from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

Comment: @Bernard I get an error: *Package amsmath Error: \begin{split} won't work here. \end{split}*, so I think I cannot use "split" when using amsmath (actually, I am not using amsmath, so I guess that the other *usepackage* I have, which is mathtools, uses amsmath)

Comment: My fault – I mistyped. `split` is indeed an `amsmath` environment (which is loaded by `mathtools`, as you guessed). I meant the `strip` environment. Sorry for the *lapsus calami*.

Comment: @Bernard Works, thanks! BTW, do you know how likely it is that the AMCS editors will ask me to find another way, and will not accept the use of split, as the style usually has two columns?